# Angular route doesn't update to child's path

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a project with file structure

```
app/
    (all the files that get automatically built)
    app-routing.module.ts
    components/
        layout/
            top/
            side/
            banner/
        pages/
            home/
            prehistory/
                prehuman/
                    australopithecine/
                    homininia/
                earlyHuman/
                    outOfAfrica/
                    agriculture/
            ancient/
                (several directories like in prehistory)
            post-classical/
                (several directories like in prehistory)
```

Each directory under `pages/` was built in the CLI with `ng g c ___` so that it has all the usual files.  I'm trying to build the router so that it reflects the directory structure with child routers, so I have in `app-routing.module.ts` the following code.  Note that since I'm at the early stages I haven't fully written out all the children and their sub-children, I just wanted to get a small part of it built and tested before building out the rest.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/pages/home/home.component';
import { PrehistoryComponent } from './components/pages/prehistory/prehistory.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', children: [
    {path:'prehistory', component:PrehistoryComponent},
    {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

In my AppComponent I used header and other tags to control CSS styles, but the important part is that there's a portion of the screen reserved for the header, for the side, and then the content which is the part that changes based on the address.

**app.component.html**

```
<header>
  <app-top></app-top>
</header>
<aside>
  <app-side></app-side>
</aside>
<content>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</content>
```

And the links are in the TopComponent.

**top.component.html**

```
<div><app-banner></app-banner></div>
<div id="breadcrumb">
  <nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['']" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    <a (mouseover)="onHover()" [routerLink]="['prehistory']" routerLinkActive="active">Prehistory</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**top.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-top',
  templateUrl: './top.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top.component.css'],
})
export class TopComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  onHover = function() {
    console.log(this.route.url._value[0]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

When my browser navigates to `/prehistory` the page loads correctly but the console prints out `""` indicating the root route URL.  And when I've also tried logging to console the parent directory, it prints `null`, confirming that the activated route is representing the root directory even though the page has navigated away from it.

**home.component.html**

```
<p>
  home works!
</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**prehistory.component.html**

```
<p>
  prehistory works!
</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Using `.forChild` instead of `.forRoot` seems to break the page.  I am wondering if maybe I need to use a service to pass information around?  Like maybe I need a service to somehow collect the current route from the content tag and pass that over to the TopComponent?  But I'm not sure how I would get a service that collects the route from the content tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important is to activate this property: **useHash: true** and then manage the path correctly with the name of each component.

Try changing to this code:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'children', component: [
    {path:'prehistory', component:PrehistoryComponent},
    {path:'**', component:HomeComponent},
  ]},
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: I tried to make the most minimal change which was adding the `useHash: true` but it didn't change the behavior--so I take it the rest of the changes are also necessary.  That looks like it means the address to prehistory would have to be `/children/prehistory` which is not the worst thing in the world.  But when I iterate this down a level, will that mean that the path to agriculture will eventually have to be `/children/prehistory/children/earlyhuman/children/agriculture`?